# Zoomo Pro USB2 iCAM stops preview / capturing after 5 to 9 minutes

Tags: windows-7, webcam

A client of mime, using Windows 7, is complaining that her Zoomo Pro USB2 iCAM (a webcam) seems to stop preview / capturing after 5 to 9 minutes.

I'm not sure if it is the hardware or the software that is causing the problem. I tried different software such as AMCap and ManyCam but these also stop preview / capturing after 5 to 9 minutes.

Anyone know if I missed out any troubleshooting steps?

Comment: It could be hard disk space, it could be a software restriction, it would be good to know what make the webcam is and also what operating system it is running on. As a thing to check first, check the computer has plenty of free disk space first.

Comment: The OS is Windows 7 and the model of the webcam is Zoomo Pro USB2 iCAM. According to the software, it classify it as USB2.0 PC Camera (SN9C203)

Comment: @IainSimpson, Yes, the computer have at least 100 GB of free space.

Comment: Are you using the Zoomo Pro software to record the videos with, or are you using something else ?.

Comment: In the future please [edit] your question and don't put the important information in the comments, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I thought the answers sections was for answers, that's why I deleted my query and put it in the comments section instead as it wasn't an answer, but just a query so that I could formulate an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It could possibly be – depending on your PC specs – that the video recording  is taking up too many system resources. I'm not sure about your PC specifications so this is just a suggestion to get started.

Press `Ctrl-Alt-Delete` and bring up the Task Manager. See what the CPU / memory usage is at the bottom of the window. If this is in the high 80's to 90's it may be causing the recording to fail. Try turning off all running programs and anything running in the system tray in the bottom right hand corner.

Is there a video recording quality setting in the software at all? I know AMCap is fairly basic so you might want to try something a bit better that has some kind of caching built into it so your disk has time to catch up – if that is the reason it is failing.

If the software has a video quality setting, try setting this to its lowest resolution / MB per second settings.

Comment: Strange. The CPU / Memory usage was below 50s. The software AMCap only have set frame rate and time limit only.